# How to add middleware for one or two controllers in Symfony4?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-flex

I want a few controllers which have methods like this:

```
public function syncAction(EntityManager $em)
{
    $posts = $em->getRepository('App:Posts')->findAllByOwner($this->getUser());

    return new JsonResponse(['ok' => true, 'posts' => $this->toJson($posts)]);
}
```

I want to add something like middleware to be automatically jsonify response from all actions of this controller. And be ablw to simple do this:

```
    return new JsonResponse(['ok' => true, 'posts' => $posts]);
```

PS Also automatically serialize my instances.

Answer (score 8):

Symfony has no middleware concept, but `event` listener and subscriber (basically the same thing).

Have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

You will use `kernel.response` (`KernelEvents::RESPONSE`) event, to manipulate the controller response.